# Cross browser centering an image and a slider

Tags: html, css, center, centering, orbit

now that my orbit slider works almost perfect, i discovered a new problem.
I'm using a macbook pro 13 inch with chrome as main browser. Everything looks ok in chrome.
However i did a browser test (on the well known website) and there it showed me that on several browsers my slider or page isn't centering like it should do.

Now my question, can someone help me solve this? so my page and slider are both centered.
I'm using a webpage that consists of a single image because it's just a little test. but in order to complete the test it should be centered.

[link to the site](http://ijsbaanheist.be)

CSS to position the body and content(content contains the image)

```
body
{
background-image: url("../afbeeldingen/bg.jpeg");
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
}

#content 
{
width: 100%;
}
```

and for the slider

```
#featured
{
position: absolute;
top: 152px;
left: 218px;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some or minimum amount of markup and CSS that exhibit the problem, then it may be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @amn Edited and inserted the css for the positioning of the elements.

Comment: Please don't set a fixed width or height to the `BODY` element, it will lead to ugly white borders in some clients…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the width and height from the body.
 
Your orbit slider uses an absolute position which means it will find the parent relative position, which is your body. So let's change your content div into:

```
#content { 
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1030px;
}
```

You can also delete this whole line:

```
#featured
{
position: absolute;
top: 152px;
left: 218px;
}
```

See how that goes for now.

Answer (score 2):

You are using absolute positioning to centre the div, and this isn't the way to go about it. This centres it for your screen resolution only! If you want to centre it, use `width: 850px; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: So basically i do the same as with the image and they will be at the same spot no matter what size?

Comment: You can assign a width then `margin:auto;` of any element and it will centre inside its PARENT element. This means to center it in the screen the parent must be as wide as the screen